# how to get second tag value

Tags: c#, html

i have following code but i want second td value how do this ? please help.

```
string value = getBetween(xml, "<td class=\"statusValue\">", "</td>");

public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    int Start, End;
    if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
    {
        Start = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
        End = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
        return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

please see below image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use Regex to get all matches:

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
{
    string pattern = string.Format("{0}((.|\n|\r)*?){1}", strStart, strEnd);
    Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
    var matchCollection = r.Matches(strSource);
    //you can iterate through collection

    foreach (Match match in r.Matches(strSource))
    {

        string textBetweenTags = match.Groups[1].ToString();
        //your logic here
    }

    //or return second value you want
    if (matchCollection.Count >= 2)
    {
        return matchCollection[1].Groups[1].ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide your xml in text please?

Comment: i mean html, sorry :)

Comment: i have full page but i want get second value this method return me first tag value i want second

Comment: your Great Thanks :)